# InvalidArgument when making curl on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm trying to use https://www.jsonstore.io to store logs from my PowerShell script, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-type: application/json" value of type
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:16
+ curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: curl is an alias for Invoke-WebRequest, if you want the real curl use curl.exe. See also `Get-Command curl*`

Comment: Please add the code where you are making the `Invoke-WebRequest` call, especially when you create the headers you pass along.

Answer (score -3):

In the error message it reads:

> url -XPOST -H **"Content-type: application/json"** -d '{

and on the line above

> Cannot convert the "Content-type: application/json" value of type
>   "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".

In other words,`Invoke-WebRequest`wants you to supply its headers as a dictionary instead of a string.

My guess is that you wrote the headers as a string (in bold in the first quote above). This need to be turned into a dictionary instead.

Try calling `Invoke-WebRequest` like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri $url -Headers @{"Content-type"="application/json"}
```

where `$url` is the URL you are calling.